# How to select an element inside "this" in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know can I select an element this way:

```
$("ul.topnav > li.target").css("border", "3px double red");
```

but how can I do something like:

```
$(this > li.target).css("border", "3px double red");
```

Answer (score 216, accepted):

```
$( this ).find( 'li.target' ).css("border", "3px double red");
```

or

```
$( this ).children( 'li.target' ).css("border", "3px double red");
```

Use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) for immediate descendants, or [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) for deeper elements.

Comment: Short-hand for find: `$('li.target',this);`

Comment: does find only return the first occurance or all the occurances?

Answer (score 9):

I use this to get the Parent, similarly for child

```
$( this ).children( 'li.target' ).css("border", "3px double red");
```

Good Luck