# How to find an element within an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the font color of a `a` tag in the `hover` function of the parent `li` tag.

I'm trying to do something like this

```
$('li').mouseover(function () {
   var a = $(this).(NEED TO FIND CORRESPONDING a TAG)
    a.css('color', 'white');
});
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select an element by class inside "this" in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868599/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-inside-this-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find('a');
```

This will find the `<a>` element inside the `<li>` element.

Even better:

```
$('li a').mouseover(function () {
   var a = $(this); // this now refers to <a>
    a.css('color', 'white');
});
```

Using the selector wisely you can save time by avoiding additional function calls.

Even better, use only a single event listener for the mouse over event, in the parent `<ul>` tag.

```
$('ul').mouseover(function (e) {
    var a = $(e.target); // e.target is the element which fired the event
    a.css('color', 'white');
});
```

This will save resources since you only use a single event listener instead of one for each `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var a = $(this).find("a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').mouseover(function () {
   var a = $("a", this);
   a.css('color', 'white');
});
```

The second argument specifies the context. So it finds all `a` in the context of `this` which is the `li`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find elements

Answer (score 0):

If your parent tag is

`<li>` and your child tag is `<div>`

then you can find child tag by using this :

```
$('li').mouseover(function () {
  var innerElement=$(this).find("div");
  innerElement.css('color', 'white');
}
```