# How to find an element within an element using the id of the element to be fetched and passed as parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386100/how-to-find-an-element-within-an-element) and accordingly found out that this piece of code here

```
var node_exists=$(treeselector).find("li[id^='someid']");
```

where treeselector is the selector to the element within which the elements to be searched for are contained.This works perfectly fine.

However when in the id^='someid' part I try to change 'someid' to some variable which contains the id then it stops working.

```
var someid='someid'
var node_exists=$(treeselector).find("li[id^=someid]");
```

I also tried concatenating single quotes when the parameter is recieved in the function where this is fired.
I think this might have to do with the double quotes surrounding the **li[id^='someid']** part. Any idea as to how to make this work?

Cheers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate:

```
var someVar = 'id1';
var node_exists=$(treeselector).find("li[id^="+someVar+"]");
```

Comment: Worked...now it sounds stupid....im a newbie sorry..will accept the answer as soon as i can

Comment: BTW, "[attribute=val]" is one of the slower (as in low performance) ways you can do a selection in jquery. you should make it a point use ID and class syntax where possible: li.someClassName or li#someIdName rather than by [attr=val]