# Call elements inside $(this)?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find an element within an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386100/how-to-find-an-element-within-an-element)

Im running a loop to go through each table row. I want to access the elements inside each table row. How do I do this?

**Table:**

```
<table>
<tr> <td class="a">x</td> <td class="b">x</td> <td class="c">x</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="a">x</td> <td class="b">x</td> <td class="c">x</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="a">x</td> <td class="b">x</td> <td class="c">x</td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="a">x</td> <td class="b">x</td> <td class="c">x</td> </tr>
</table>
```

**Code doesnt work:**

```
$("tr").each(function(index) {

    // get class a text
    $(this + " td.a").text();

    // get class b text
    $(this + " td.b").text();

    // get class c text
    $(this + " td.c").text();

});
```

Comment: Read the API docs. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing

Comment: Also, the jQuery API contains all the information you need. Take an hour or two to go through it, it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
$("tr").each(function(index) {

    // get class a text
    var text1 = $(this).children("td.a").text();

    // get class b text
    var text2 = $(this).children("td.b").text();

    // get class c text
    var text2 = $(this).children("td.c").text();

});
```

Comment: I tried this before posting and it didnt work. But now it does!! THANK YOU.

Comment: You are welcome :) Be attentive!

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter of the jQuery function is *context*:

```
$("td.a", this).text();
```

This will find all `td.a` descendants that fall within `this`.

Answer (score 3):

If you were accessing it "normally" (ie. not with jQuery), you can just get the `cells` property.

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), l = trs.length, i, tds;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    tds = trs[i].cells;
    // do stuff with tds
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to call `$(this)` multiple times, you should assign it to a local variable to increase performance. See this post for more information:

[$this vs $(this) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389944/this-vs-this-in-jquery)

Finally, you can use `.find()` for what you are trying to achieve:

```
$("tr").each(function(index) {

    var $this = $(this);

    // get class a text
    $this.find("td.a").text();

    // get class b text
    $this.find("td.b").text();

    // get class c text
    $this.find("td.c").text();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tr").each(function(index) {

    // get class a text
    $("td.a", this).text();

    // get class b text
    $("td.b", this).text();

    // get class c text
    $("td.c", this).text();

});
```

Comment: THANKS I didnt know you could structure it like that!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        aText = $this.find('.a').text(),
        bText = $this.find('.b').text(),
        cText = $this.find('.c').text();
});
```