# Get tag inside this javascript

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
         $('li').click(function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).addClass("active1");

     // $(this a).addClass("acolor");  // I am trying  this

});;
```

Anchor tag is inside li tag and on click of li I want to change color of a text - which is there in css in .acolor class

in this I am getting li, and I want to get a tag.

Any help will be appreciated !! Thanks

Comment: I found the duplicate by searching for [`[jquery] find element inside this`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+find+element+inside+this), which let me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604251/call-elements-inside-this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$(this).find('a').addClass("acolor");
```

---

Or provide `this` as the [context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) in the jQuery method.

```
$('a', this).addClass("acolor");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pranav !! It worked for me :)

Comment: After adding this as active , how can I remove it once I click another li and remove from current li?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee `$(this).sibling().find('a').removeClass("acolor");`