# targeting specific jQuery element with identical class name

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select an element by class inside “this” in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868599/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-inside-this-in-jquery)

I'm newer to jQuery...I think this has something to do with using a 'this" command but not sure.

I have a page that is programmatically creating several divs like this:

```
<div class="moreinfolink">Click For More Information
<div class="moreinfotext">Additional Info Here</div>
</div>
```

So there are several .moreinfolink and .moreinfotext classes on a page.

I used this code to toggle showing the moreinfotext div:

```
$('.moreinfolink').click(function() {
  $('.moreinfotext').toggle('slow', function() {
  });
```

But this obviously does a toggle for ALL of the moreinfotext divs that exist on the page.

Two questions:
How can I do it for the specific child div that is inside the parent moreinfolink div?
Is there a better way to do it than the direciton I'm going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) (as @FelixKling suggests):

```
$('.moreinfolink').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.moreinfotext').toggle('slow', function() { ... });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hejFq/

Comment: Internally, `$('.moreinfotext', this)` calls `$(this).find('.moreinfotext')`, so you can use that directly.

Comment: @FelixKling: You're right, and I suppose calling `find` directly is better.

Comment: That got it!  Is the way I'm using the HTML here the best way to do it or is there a better method?

Comment: @ChrisCummings: I'd say that method is fine, especially if you don't really have control over the markup you're working with

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle shows you how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAwTL/

Or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAwTL/1/), which shows calling the `find()` method directly as Felix Kling suggests.

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="moreinfolink">Click For More Information
<div class="moreinfotext">Additional Info Here</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="moreinfolink">Click For More Information
<div class="moreinfotext">Additional Info Here</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="moreinfolink">Click For More Information
<div class="moreinfotext">Additional Info Here</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.moreinfolink').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.moreinfotext').toggle('slow', function() { });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.moreinfolink').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.moreinfotext').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

I removed the empty function you had... either there wasn't enough info provided to support it, ir it was there in error.