# How is this span related to a b hook tag for targeting?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have this mark-up:

```
<b class="learn more">
Learn more <span class="closedTriangle">&#x25BA;</span><span class="openTriangle">&#x25BC;</span>
</b>
```

and this jquery:

```
$('.learnMore').click(function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
    $('.learnMore + .closedTriangle').toggle();
    $('.learnMore + .openTriangle').toggle();
});
```

I've tried wrapping the selector with $(this), but I see the mark-up is not in this context.

I was trying to use and adjacent selector but I'm not winning yet. I am trying to toggle the show/hide between the arrows but only within the specific context. I have numerous "learn More"'s around the page so just selecting the classes would affect all of them on the page

Comment: You're using the wrong css selectors. what are you trying to do? give us a full example

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select an element by class inside "this" in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868599/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-inside-this-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/onunus/2/edit)*

- You had a typo in HTML (class name)
- and inside the jQuery just reference to  `this parent` like: `$('YourChildrenElementOf', this)`

HTML:

```
  <b class="learnMore">  <!-- FIXED CLASS NAME TYPO -->
Learn more <span class="closedTriangle">&#x25BA;</span><span class="openTriangle">&#x25BC;</span>
</b>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.learnMore').click(function() {
    $('span', this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roko... it's one of those weekends where you just need another set of eyes and another brain to jumpstart ones own back into the game!

Comment: @lbreau :D no problem. Glad we did it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the + in the selector.

```
$('.learnMore  .closedTriangle')
```

means all elements with class .closedTriangle that are under an element with class .learnMore

Also, please note, that in your markup, the  has 2 separate classes, learn and more. There is no element with .learnMore class