# jQuery toggle between two classes inside this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function () {
        $(".down, .up").toggleClass("down up");
    });
```

And this works, but I want it to toggle between the two classes inside `this` dropdown element, currently it toggles between two classes for all .dropdown elements.

I know you can do this $(".down", this).... but how would I apply that to both .down and .up?

Comment: Exactly as you already are... `$(".down, .up", this)`. Also note that it would seem that CSS is a much better alternative to JS for this logic.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Trying that now

Comment: Yup, that works, if you put it in answer ill accept it.

Comment: Thanks. I added it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an element by class inside "this" in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868599/how-to-select-an-element-by-class-inside-this-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or it could be:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".down, .up").toggleClass("down up");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by simply adding the `this` context to the selector you're already using, for example:

```
$(".dropdown").hover(function () {
  $(".down, .up", this).toggleClass("down up");
});
```

However I'd suggest that using CSS would be a much better alternative. It's more semantic, and also performs much better:

```css
.dropdown .down { color: red; }
.dropdown .up { color: blue; }

.dropdown:hover .down { color: blue; }
.dropdown:hover .up { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="up">Up</div>
  <div class="down">Down</div>
</div><br />

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="up">Up</div>
  <div class="down">Down</div>
</div>
```