# Tag selector with 'this' keyword selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me I want use tag selector with 'this' keyword selector. Below its example:

`$(this 'h3').text();`

but its show error so please let me how can I use it correctly

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select an element inside "this" in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868599/how-to-select-an-element-inside-this-in-jquery)

Comment: `$()` is a function, and as such, you gotta pass arguments properly separated by `,`. Right now, you're passing `$(this 'something')`, with nothing separating `this` and `"something"`. Regardless of what you're trying to do, that's not even valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to find an `<h3>` element in `this`, you can use:

```
$("h3", this).text();
```

This is the same as:

```
$(this).find("h3").text();
```

For example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert($("h3", this).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><h3>Hello World</h3></button>
```